# Is there a way to use declared/set range variable in excel formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying use the declared range and apply it to an excel formula within the sheet.

[Excel data is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY8aI.png)

***Macro Code:***

```
Sub VariableRange()

Set CodeRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(8, 2))
Set AmountRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(8, 4))
Set DateRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(8, 5))
    
    Range("I5").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(R2C4:R8C4,R2C2:R8C2,R[-2]C,R2C5:R8C5,R[-1]C)"

End Sub
```

is there a way for me to declare the range and or cells in a way like this?

```
Range("I5").Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & AmountRange & " ," & CodeRange & " ," & Range("I3") & " ," & DateRange & " ," & Range("I4") & " ,)"
```

Edit: Adjusted 2nd macro code

Comment: If you want to write a formula, you need to concatenate in the range addresses.

Comment: @BigBen is there any other way? since the range has already been declared? If None , How should it be done if it needs concatenation?

Comment: You need to concatenate each range's  `.Address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Writing `SUMIFS` Formula in VBA

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VariableRange()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 3 ' don't include headers
    Const CodeColumn As String = "B"
    Const DateColumn As String = "E"
    Const AmountColumn As String = "D"
    Const FindCodeCellAddress As String = "I3"
    Const FindDateCellAddress As String = "I4"
    Const FindAmountCellAddress As String = "I5"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, CodeColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim CodeRange As Range
    Set CodeRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, CodeColumn), _
        ws.Cells(LastRow, CodeColumn))
    
    Dim DateRange As Range
    Set DateRange = CodeRange.EntireRow.Columns(DateColumn)
    Dim AmountRange As Range
    Set AmountRange = CodeRange.EntireRow.Columns(AmountColumn)
    
    ws.Range(FindAmountCellAddress).Formula = _
        "=SUMIFS(" & AmountRange.Address & "," _
        & CodeRange.Address & "," & FindCodeCellAddress & "," _
        & DateRange.Address & "," & FindDateCellAddress & ")"
    
    ' Result in cell 'FindAmountCellAddress' if last row is 8:
    ' =SUMIFS($D$3:$D$8,$B$3:$B$8,I3,$E$3:$E$8,I4)

End Sub
```